# wp-cron not working

Tags: wp-cron

This is a wp-cron I defined in `function.php` file, but I don't get any result in the error log, the event is in the cron list but if I launch it nothing happens.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

```
function cron_daily_whatever() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('check_daily_event')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(),'daily','check_daily_event');
  }
}

function my_do_this_daily() {
    error_log('check');
}

add_action('wp','cron_daily_whatever');
add_action('check_daily_event','my_do_this_daily');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    
function cron_daily_whatever() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('check_daily_event')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(),'daily','check_daily_event');
  }
}

function check_daily_event() {
    error_log('check');
}

add_action('wp','cron_daily_whatever');
add_action('check_daily_event','check_daily_event');
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer should help.

Comment: I have just developed a regular task is to work this way, it is so can be implemented，Or you check the timestamp of the task's time () is accurate

Comment: echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>';

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14446/how-to-test-wp-cron

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/how-to-debug-wordpress-cron-wp-schedule-event

Comment: Please, always add [edit]s instead of comments. It's much better to read and comments are meant to be cleaned up and deleted. If you believe there are other questions that are the same, then please flag the question for closing as duplicate. Thanks. About code-only answers: Please take your time to explain (in the answer) what the code is about and why it should work – especially if it's the same code as in the question ;). Thanks for the answer, your time and I hope you continue to have a good time here on the site.